# MaterializeCSS onAutocomplete not triggering javascript callback function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, materialize

I am using Materialize CSS to create a Google Web App linked to our company's Google Drive for some basic document flow processes. I am trying to create an autocomplete text field that when a user begins typing the name it populates options and when an option is selected it triggers the onAutocomplete callback and autofills some following fields based off of the client selected. Getting the field to autocomplete is no problem, but I can't get the onAutocomplete callback to trigger.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <?!= include("pageCSS"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row input-field">
        <input  class="autocomplete"type="text" id="autocompleteField"/>
        <label for="infoModalName">Client Name</label>
    </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"> 
  </script>
  <?!= include("pageScripts"); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<script>
function populateWords(words){
        
    //console.log(words)

    var autoComplete = document.getElementById("autocompleteField");
    M.Autocomplete.init(autoComplete, {data: words}, {onAutocomplete: function() 
       {console.log("Hello")}});

}
</script>
```

Right now, I am just trying to get the callback function to output anything, not write to the other fields. A lot of the documentation online uses the JQuery setup, but this is the last thing I need to get working and I have not used any JQuery to this point, so I would rather stick with a Javascript solution if possible.

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between your HTML and the function of `populateWords`?

Comment: Yes, of course. My `DOMContentLoaded` event listener calls `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateData).getAutoFillData()` which pulls our client names from our google spreadsheet and returns it to `populateWords()` The autocomplete part works perfectly, just not the callback.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between `function populateWords(words){,,,}` and `populateData` of `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateData).getAutoFillData()`. Where is the function `populateData`? And also, can you provide the sample value of `words`?

Comment: Although unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't know the value of `words` in your script, I proposed a modified script using a sample value of `words` to an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Comment: I apologize, `populateWords()` is one of my scripts. I edited my question to include `<script>`. and it should be `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateWords).getAutoFillData()` not `populateData`, I was making some changes since I posted the question and I didn't realize. the format of words is as follows: `words = {CBX Global=false, Client=false, RPM Partners=false, I. L. Long Construction Co., Inc.=false}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the arguments of `M.Autocomplete.init` is like `M.Autocomplete.init(elems, options)`. [Ref](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) And also, it seems that the value of `words` is required to be an object. When these are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, please modify `populateWords` as follows.

```js
function populateWords(words){
  words = {key: "value"};  // This is a sample value for testing this modification.
  var autoComplete = document.getElementById("autocompleteField");
  M.Autocomplete.init(autoComplete, {data: words, onAutocomplete: function() {console.log("Hello")}});
}
```

- In this modification, when `k` is put to the text input, the autoComplete is run and when `key` is selected, `console.log("Hello")` is run.

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't know the value of `words` in your script. So I used a sample value. Please modify it for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [Autocomplete](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html)

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much, I have been struggling with this for three days. I knew it had to be something simple. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Thedornman Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.